# compute neurons distance in self organizing map for clustering

Tags: self-organizing-maps

I want to use self organizing map for clustering. I am using 10 neurons that implies there are 100 clusters with elements in them. How to compute the distance of a neuron with its neighboring neurons

Answer (score 0):

The number of clusters depend on the number of output neurons you have set.

I suggest use euclidean distance measure to compute the distance. Hope this helps